# Deep link not working from Chrome Custom Tabs with device having old version of Chrome

Tags: android, deep-linking, chrome-custom-tabs

I launch ChromeCustomTabs from my app. The page in chorme custom tabs show a button. On click of that button a deep link is triggered, something like this `myapp://show/screen?id=123`. My corresponding intent-filter is like this:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
                <data android:host="show"
                    android:path="/screen"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

**Problem**: When user taps on that button, it launches my app only if the version of chrome is recent or latest 74.*.* Whereas it doesn't trigger my app on older versions of chrome browser e.g. on 65.*.*

Comment: I have found the "data" part of intent filters to be a bit buggy and sometimes they don't function "as advertised". You could try removing the `path` and setting a `pathPattern="/.*"` instead. Or use the "intent syntax" to launch the intent from a HTML anchor. For example, in your case it'll be  `<a href="intent://show/screen?id=123#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=your.app.package.name;end">Click me</a>`

Comment: @Leo unfortunately both of the options didn't work for me. Problem is whatever intent-filter setting,  deep-link intent is, they work on higher version of chrome browser but not on lower version.

Comment: If you open regular Chrome instead for Chrome Custom Tabs, does the deeplink work?

Comment: @andreban yes it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out to be a well known issue. I was getting a `Navigation is Blocked` console message when I connect my emulators dev tools in browser. Google Chrome won't let a deeplink to open an app, if it is triggered by a javascript. It has to be a user initiated action. In my case after the user clicks on button, there were series of things done behind ajax call, before deeplink was triggered.

As a workaround, once the button is clicked and web is done with all the ajax calls, it redirects to **new** intermediate screen. This screen was created with a button for user to click(Continue). On click of this button, deeplink successfully redirected to app.

Comment: Hi @LoveForDroid. I'm facing this issue, Gmail opens my links with Chrome Tabs and the final page with the user action button "Take me back to the app" doesn't trigger my intent-filter. Can you update your response with your code sample showing how you setup your intent filter and your <a href>? Thanks.